# The program takes input infinitely

Tags: c++, input

The following code segment is to take input `t` (the number of test cases) and number of    students `n[w]` and a number `g[w]`. then it should height of students as the input and store it in the array `stu` whose maximum size `MAXV` is `100`.But this loop goes on forever.What possibly might be wrong in this?

```
int t;
cin>>t;
std::vector<int> n(t);
std::vector<int> g(t);
int m =0;
int stu[MAXV];
for(int w=0;w<t;t++)
{
    cin>>n[w]>>g[w];
    for(int i=m;i<n[w] && i < MAXV;i++)
    {
        cin>>stu[i];
       ++m;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not *infinitely*, but it will accept input a few billion times... You set `w` to 0, but you increment `t`.

Comment: may you meant `w++` instead of `t++` in the first for-loop

Comment: Another thing: when the inner loop hits `MAXV`, the outer loop keeps looping.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int w=0;w<t;t++)
{

}
```

This is an infinite loop. Once t was greater than w, it will be always greater. Incremet w instead of t if You want it to stop.

Correction: it isn't infinite, after overflow, it will stop.

Comment: It's not an *infinite* loop. It will exit after a few billion times.

Comment: You're right. It will stop after the owerflow.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: Yup, just be patient, give it a little time...

Comment: ok ok, i accept thats a foolish mistake

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int w=0;w<t;t++) , really ?
```

I'm sure you meant

```
for(int w=0;w<t;w++)
```

Check for other errors too, but this is why you coded an infinite loop

Comment: +1, but that "*really?*" is not necessary.

Comment: that was so stupid of me...

Comment: that was so stupid of me...
Thanks for the help